# How to disable CORS for google chrome in android studio emulator?

Tags: android-studio, same-origin-policy

I am running my localhost web app in android studio emulator using port forwarding.
But from server I get CORS error for backend APIs.
I solved the issue on desktop using CORS disable extension or by opening google chrome with disabled security flag.
How can CORS be disabled in google chrome in mobile device or android studio emulator?

Comment: What's the web app? You can enable/disable features of CORS globally via the web app/

Comment: By web app I meant react app I am using.

Comment: The goal described in the question isn’t disabling CORS but instead disabling the same-origin policy.

Comment: please share you setup info what's you backend service is in, request made from frontend, what's the error you are getting?

Comment: @Alwaysalearner were you able to find a solution that works for you from this?

Comment: @TheFunk Going to go through https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

CORS is typically something you tweak as a server side/API side kinda thing. You're developing a React app, and React is frontend only, so you're using something else as your backend. If you're using express, you can just npm install cors and then require it, and the server will accept requests [or you can manually set the headers](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html). You can do that same sorta thing with [Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework), [Javalin](https://javalin.io/documentation#configuration), [Flask](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and a host of other servers/server side frameworks.

Let's say you're more familiar with React or you don't have access to the backend, another option is to use a proxy or a middleware while you're developing, in order to get rid of those errors and trick your backend and frontend into thinking that they're not talking cross-origin. [Here's a good article about a React proxy middleware that intercepts requests and changes the origin.](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app)

Edit: Just to provide a little more info, you can use browser extensions like you're doing or set security flags in your browser but that's kind of a hacky way to get around CORS protections and as you can see, when you want to use a different browser for testing your frontend or maybe you want to test on a different device (android emulator), you run into this issue again because those headers are set server side.

Comment: Hi, I am going to read and try https://www.telerik.com/blogs/dealing-with-cors-in-create-react-app as I don't have access to server side code at the moment.
But we are using nginx webserver and I think we can make changes in nginx setup to allow Cross origin request in case of localhost. but I am not sure about that method.
I will update if above article help.

Comment: http://oskarhane.com/avoid-cors-with-nginx-proxy_pass/
This is the article which has explained about Avoiding CORS with Nginx proxy_pass, but I did not understand the steps.

Comment: @Alwaysalearner Nginx can be configured in the same way that React can using the article I linked.  In other words, you can use Nginx to proxy traffic between your backend and frontend. In the link you provided, the user is using Nginx to proxy the connections between the client and the server and modify request and response headers to remove details about the origin. In the case of the user on that page they defined two "servers" in their Nginx config, one acting as the proxy and modifying the headers, before forwarding downstream to the other one serving the backend API.